# php 5.3.2-1 code not working on php 5.3.8

Tags: php, yii, xampp

My code was working fine in php 5.3.2-1 on ubuntu. I recently ported it to windows with XAMPP installed in it. It uses php 5.3.8 . I am getting error.

```
 Non-static method Following::getUpdates() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

What is way to go?
Shall i correct my code to replace declaration at each place in code  OR
Is there way to simulate the old behavior(php 5.3.2 with php.ini file) because i am not sure how much more error will be thrown at my face after correcting it.

UPDATE (code sample)

```
public function actionIndex(){
        if(yii::app()->user->isGuest){
            $this->render('guestIndex');
        }
        else{
            $dataProvider = Following::getUpdates(yii::app()->user->id);    //genrerate data for the homepage of user i.e updates from followers
            $this->render('userIndex',array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));
        }


    }
```

Getting the error on line `$dataProvider = Following::getUpdates(yii::app()->user->id);`
I am using yii framework.

Comment: Are you doing $this::DoSomething() and not MyObject::DoSomething() ?

Comment: I have called a non-static function with static object. But the code was working fine with older version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your new installation likely just includes `E_STRICT` warnings while your previous installation didn't. [Quoting the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> Calling non-static methods statically generates an `E_STRICT` level warning.

This implies you can get rid of the warnings by disabling `E_STRICT` in your [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting), but IMO you should fix the offending code.

Comment: Removing E_STRICT worked. I wondered why it didn't worked at first time. I reinstalled the XAMPP and it worked this time. Probably i must have screwed with ini file last time. Thanks

Comment: I have used call by reference at one place which is also deprecated "Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated ". Any work-aroud for this except returning the values ?

Comment: @Terminal returning the values sounds like a really good and clean idea imo, but have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055812/how-to-avoid-call-time-pass-by-reference-deprecated-error-in-php

Comment: Sure that is clean but just avoiding to change the code. Thanks again, changing the syntax worked :)