# Deprecated error in pass by reference in latest version of localhost

Tags: php, localhost

All the project is error free on localhost vertrigo_222 (and also on livehost).

Now I am trying to upgrade my localhost to latest version vertrigo_230.

I am facing following deprecated error:
[image]

Here is line number 1170 and 1171:

```
calculate_city_row_col($row['attacker_city_id'], &$att_city_row, &$att_city_col);
calculate_city_row_col($row['defender_city_id'], &$def_city_row, &$def_city_col);
```

Please give me some solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid call-time pass-by-reference deprecated error in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055812/how-to-avoid-call-time-pass-by-reference-deprecated-error-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try remove & before $att_city_row and $att_city_col, $def_city_row, $def_city_col

Comment: That's just encouraging duplicate questions. If the OP would've just pasted the error message in google, he would've found the solution....

Comment: It's not solution. If author need values after method's treatment then it will be other solution, like rewriting his methods.